# HTML + Jquery web app with windows - duplicate IDs and duplicate Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my web app. Its UI is window based, so there can be many windows opened at the same time. These windows are DIVs which are loaded with AJAX call. Everything works fine when the content of all the windows is unique.

However, sometimes its needed to have 2 or more same windows opened at the same time. Loaded AJAX content in both windows has same HTML ID attributes, same JS functions and same global variables used for this particular window. Then obviously all breaks up.

I am looking for a way how to solve this problem. The only one, which came to my mind is to change using ID attributes and use classes instead. JS functions can be shared and loaded when the whole user interfaces loads up at start up. But what about those global variables with the same names ?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML id attributes have to be unique in the context of the whole document. You can hack it or rethink it.

If you decide to rethink - consider also global variables.

Help in rethinking: if you use ids to recognize objects you can use patterns like this:

w11-22222

where w is just a letter (ids shouldn't start with a number), 11 is a window numner, - is a - ;) and 22222 is the id you used up to now.

When you need the old id it's just `id.substring(4)`

global variables should be replaced with a global object holding arrays/objects containing information about windows etc.

**Just a thought:**

It is possible to engeneer the interface in a way you would not need ids to get windows. When creating a window do:

```
var $awindow=$('<div></div>')...//build upon it with attr and append
$awindow.appendTo('body');
AwesomeGlobalObjectToControllStuff.rememberWindow('the key to find it',$awindow);
```

And then use the object to return the $awindow from its storage.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was thinking about doing something similar, so you have just confirmed my thoughts. Oh well, a lot of nasty work ahead :-(

Comment: Depending on the application - there might be a single place in the whole thing where you could assure unique ids. I don't know the app, so it's just a general solution.